# adding a number to a numerical string with jquery

Tags: jquery, text, addition, counter, increment

I have a counter and I'm trying to retrieve that number with jquery and add to it.

```
<div id='counter'>
32
</div>
```

So I'm trying to get the 32 with jquery and then add to it, +1.

```
var counter = $('#counter').text();
var counterPlus = counter++;
```

Is this supposed to work? It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a basic different between counter++ and ++counter.

counter++ -> Assign and Increment

++counter -> Increment and Assign

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/me3Yu/) Code for proof

Answer (score 8):

The type of counter is string, not number, so you need to convert it to number first:

```
var counterPlus = parseInt(counter, 10) + 1;
```

If you want to set it back:

```
$('#counter').text(parseInt($('#counter').text(), 10) + 1);
```

Comment: @andrewliu it specifies the radix to use. This prevents unexpected behavior when the input contains leading zeroes. RTFD, as they say: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Unnecessary. The `counter++` expression works just fine. The issue is that OP is expecting incremented value to be returned, which is achieved by `++counter`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var counter = parseInt(jQuery("#counter").text(), 10);
var counterPlus = counter++;
```

Comment: conversion wasn't the issue.. it was about counter++ and ++counter. See my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/skram/me3Yu/

Comment: counterPlus = counter++; //counterPlus = 32 counter = 33 <br />
counterPlus = ++counter; //counterPlus = 33 counter = 33 
counterPlus = counter+1; //counterPlus = 33 counter = 32